# WatchKit: Can I use text-to-speech?

Tags: text-to-speech, watchkit, apple-watch

I am creating an application for the new Apple Watch. I would like to use text-to-speech functionality. Right now, I'm using the old code (iPhone):

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
    speechPaused = YES;
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:@""];
    utterance.rate = 0.15;
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"it_IT"];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

In my *simulator* it works correctly for the watch.

I am confused, because I've read on several forums that it is not possible to use text-to-speech.
I'd like to know if my code works in a *real* Apple Watch.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer) the AVSpeechSynthesizer API is available for watchOS 2+.

In addition, as of June 9, 2017, I can verify that I can play an AVSpeechUtterance on my wrist on an actual device, a Series 0 Apple Watch, 38mm, which can play from the built-in speaker or through bluetooth headphones (BeatsX).

Comment: Can you load all the same voices on to your watch that you are able to load on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. In general, WatchKit is pretty limited right now. Third-party developers can currently not play audio from Apple Watch (Source: Apple employee via developer forum).

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH8-SW1) what's possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If Apple does not allow you to use text-to-speech (Watch) ... because the class AVSpeechSynthesizer works in the simulator?
and this a bug?
I would be very happy if xcode launched an alert type:
Attention can not use the class AVSpeechSynthesizer to Watch "Unfortunately this does not appear.
Appearance future updates from Apple.
Thank you.